# Firebase Array into AngularChart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angular-chart

I tried to turn this database

[image]

to be radar chart using angular-chart.

I'm wondering how to turn my Firebase array to be a new array compatible with this angular-chart array format?

```
  $scope.labels =["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running", "Running", "Running", "Running"];
            $scope.data = [[12,14,23,56,64,34,46,34,76,12]];
```

[image]

I tried this but it failed

```
 $scope.labels =$scope.results.$id;
 $scope.data = [$scope.results.$value];
```

**Edited:**
this is my own answer base on digit's knowledge

```
  $scope.labels = [], $scope.dataRaw = [], $scope.data = [];

              fireBaseData.refUser().child($scope.user_info.uid).child("result")
                .orderByValue()

                .on("value", function(snapshot){
                   snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                     console.log("The "+ data.key()+" score is "+ data.val());
                     $scope.labels.push(data.key());
                     $scope.dataRaw.push(data.val());
                    });
                });
                $scope.data.push($scope.dataRaw);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually by doing this

```
// Initialise array
$scope.labels = [], $scope.dataRaw = [], $scope.data = [];

// Fetch results in form of array of object 
angular.forEach($scope.results, function (obj) {
    $scope.labels.push(obj["$id"]);
    $scope.dataRaw.push(obj["$value"]);
});

// Store data array into new array
$scope.data.push($scope.dataRaw);
```

Comment: my `$scope.results`  shows this in output 

`[{"$value":37.5,"$id":"item1","$priority":null},{"$value":34,"$id":"item10","$priority":null},{"$value":79.5,"$id":"item2","$priority":null},{"$value":53,"$id":"item3","$priority":null},{"$value":37.5,"$id":"item4","$priority":null},{"$value":64,"$id":"item5","$priority":null},{"$value":50,"$id":"item6","$priority":null},{"$value":56,"$id":"item7","$priority":null},{"$value":60.5,"$id":"item8","$priority":null},{"$value":52,"$id":"item9","$priority":null}]`

Comment: Oh, then it will be a lot easier if it has key already. I ll update my answer.

Comment: it still shows null and undefined labels
this my example how snapshot key and value on my method, can you please apply with your method? 

`fireBaseData.refUser().child($scope.user_info.uid).child("result")
                .orderByValue()
                
                .on("value", function(snapshot){
                   snapshot.forEach(function(data){
                     console.log("The "+ data.key()+" score is "+ data.val());
                     
                 
                   });
                });`

Comment: Hi.. u need to check if data.key() == 'id' / data.key() == 'label', then you can push its value to array.

Comment: Do that in snapshot loop.

Comment: thanks, i updated my question, with your references, it works well